# jqxTree scrolling to the top by collapse/expand nodes

Tags: javascript, html, jqxwidgets

When I collapse or expand a node in a jqxTree the scrollbar of the container element is going to the top.

Is it possible to avoid this behaviour?

The solution of setting a fix height to the widget is not good for me. I need dynamic height. It is possible only if I have a conainer div with scrollbar.

http://jsfiddle.net/ccegq/633/

To reproduce the problem, open the fiddle scroll down and collapse/expand any node.

html:

```
<div id='div1'>
  <div id='jqxTree'>
      <ul>
          <li item-selected='true'>Home</li>
          <li item-expanded='true'>Solutions
              <ul>
                  <li>Education</li>
                  <li>Financial services</li>
                  <li>Government</li>
                  <li>Manufacturing</li>
                  <li>Solutions
                      <ul>
                          <li>Consumer photo and video</li>
                          <li>Mobile</li>
                          <li>Rich Internet applications</li>
                          <li>Technical communication</li>
                          <li>Training and eLearning</li>
                          <li>Web conferencing</li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>All industries and solutions</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li item-expanded='true'>Solutions
              <ul>
                  <li>Education</li>
                  <li>Financial services</li>
                  <li>Government</li>
                  <li>Manufacturing</li>
                  <li>Solutions
                      <ul>
                          <li>Consumer photo and video</li>
                          <li>Mobile</li>
                          <li>Rich Internet applications</li>
                          <li>Technical communication</li>
                          <li>Training and eLearning</li>
                          <li>Web conferencing</li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>All industries and solutions</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li item-expanded='true'>Solutions
              <ul>
                  <li>Education</li>
                  <li>Financial services</li>
                  <li>Government</li>
                  <li>Manufacturing</li>
                  <li>Solutions
                      <ul>
                          <li>Consumer photo and video</li>
                          <li>Mobile</li>
                          <li>Rich Internet applications</li>
                          <li>Technical communication</li>
                          <li>Training and eLearning</li>
                          <li>Web conferencing</li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>All industries and solutions</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li item-expanded='true'>Solutions
              <ul>
                  <li>Education</li>
                  <li>Financial services</li>
                  <li>Government</li>
                  <li>Manufacturing</li>
                  <li>Solutions
                      <ul>
                          <li>Consumer photo and video</li>
                          <li>Mobile</li>
                          <li>Rich Internet applications</li>
                          <li>Technical communication</li>
                          <li>Training and eLearning</li>
                          <li>Web conferencing</li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>All industries and solutions</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li item-expanded='true'>Solutions
              <ul>
                  <li>Education</li>
                  <li>Financial services</li>
                  <li>Government</li>
                  <li>Manufacturing</li>
                  <li>Solutions
                      <ul>
                          <li>Consumer photo and video</li>
                          <li>Mobile</li>
                          <li>Rich Internet applications</li>
                          <li>Technical communication</li>
                          <li>Training and eLearning</li>
                          <li>Web conferencing</li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>All industries and solutions</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li item-expanded='true'>Solutions
              <ul>
                  <li>Education</li>
                  <li>Financial services</li>
                  <li>Government</li>
                  <li>Manufacturing</li>
                  <li>Solutions
                      <ul>
                          <li>Consumer photo and video</li>
                          <li>Mobile</li>
                          <li>Rich Internet applications</li>
                          <li>Technical communication</li>
                          <li>Training and eLearning</li>
                          <li>Web conferencing</li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>All industries and solutions</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li item-expanded='true'>Solutions
              <ul>
                  <li>Education</li>
                  <li>Financial services</li>
                  <li>Government</li>
                  <li>Manufacturing</li>
                  <li>Solutions
                      <ul>
                          <li>Consumer photo and video</li>
                          <li>Mobile</li>
                          <li>Rich Internet applications</li>
                          <li>Technical communication</li>
                          <li>Training and eLearning</li>
                          <li>Web conferencing</li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>All industries and solutions</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

$('#jqxTree').jqxTree({
       theme: 'energyblue'
   });

CSS:

```
#div1 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#jqxTree').jqxTree({
       theme: 'energyblue',
       height:300
   });
```

Set a hieght for the tree. This will solve your problem.
The scroll you seen is not from jqxTree.I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote in my question: "The solution of setting a fix height to the widget is not good for me."

Comment: Calculate the height programmically. for eg:  $( window ).height();
 
// Returns height of HTML document
$( document ).height();